# How to unset namespace in php to access global class

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I have a lot of SDKs which have the same class names so I have moved them into folders and created namespaces. These sdks are generally used to access APIs.

```
//directory e.g. vendor/company/sdk/files

vendors/ebat/feeback/environment.php
```

I then have completely separate libraries which I have created myself which contain any methods I need to interact with these sdks. also namespaced.

```
//directory e.g.
library/marketplace/ebay/feedback.php
```

Not sure what the correct terminology is but within these libraries are some ***global*** objects e.g. `stdClass` and `ReflectionClass` which a cant seem to access/find.

**feedback.php**

```
namespace Marketplace\Ebay;

class Feedback extends \Ebat\Feedback\EbatNsFeedback_Environment {

    //simple example 
    public function new_ReflectionClass($obj){
        return new ReflectionClass($obj); 
    }
}
```

Now if I were to try and call this method

```
$this->marketplace->ebay->feedback->new_ReflectionClass(new stdClass()));
```

this error is shown.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Marketplace\Ebay\ReflectionClass' not found
```

When I add a backslash

```
 return new \ReflectionClass($obj);
```

it then gives me this error

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Ebat\Feedback\ReflectionObject' not fount
```

How can I access the native/global `ReflectionClass` class,  all similar questions seem to be fixed by adding a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a leading `\` is the correct way to access top-level namespaces/classes.

But it seems you're running in to a similar error elsewhere - note that your 2nd fatal error is about Reflection**Object**, not Reflection**Class**. Do you have other code that tries to access `ReflectionObject`?

Also, note that you can also import these namespace-less classes if you don't want to prefix every reference with a `\`

```
namespace Marketplace\Ebay;

use \ReflectionClass;

class Feedback extends \Ebat\Feedback\EbatNsFeedback_Environment {

    //simple example 
    public function new_ReflectionClass($obj){
        return new ReflectionClass($obj); 
    }
}
```